# Excel: sum this row of named ranged columns

Tags: excel, named-ranges

I have a dynamic number of columns that i add via VBA. These columns are a named range. How can I sum the current row of all the columns in that named range?

Example:

```
____|  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |  E  |
  1 |     | 123 | 100 | aaa | 223 |
  2 |     | 111 | 101 | eee | 212 |
  3 |     | 112 | 102 | xxx | 214 |
  4 |     | 197 | 103 | yyy | 300 |
  5 |     | 176 | 104 | zzz | 280 |
```

let's say columns `B` and `C` are a named range called `ser_ua`. I don't know if there will be no columns at all in this named range or if there will be 50 columns. How can i sum the current row "slice" in (in this case) `E`?

Answer (score 2):

You can 'slice' off a column with the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a), using the [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) to find the last number in the first row.

```
=sum(index(ser_ua, 0, match(1e99, 1:1)))
```

Any other column could be 'sliced' off using the *column_num* parameter of INDEX either with a hard-coded number or some formula returning a number.

[image: SUM over INDEX slice]

If ser_ua is a named range starting at B2 then you cannot ask for hte column number of the last number in row 1. You would have to ask for the last number on the first row of ser_ua.

```
=sum(index(ser_ua, 0, match(1E+99, index(ser_ua, 1, 0))))
```

[image: SUM over INDEX slice]

Comment: I've tried your function, but i can't understand it...i've read the pages you've linked and tried to break down the function without success. From what i undestood, `index(ser_ua, 0,` picks up the first value on the left and `match(1e99, 1:1)` should "move the pointer" on the next column on the right until the end? I'm asking this because i can't get it to work...

Comment: `index(ser_ua, ` means all of ser_ua. `, 0, ` means all of the rows, not a specific one like index is typically used for. `, match(1e99, 1:1)` means find the *column_num* of the last number in row 1. So is *ser_ua* is A1:Z99 but the last number in row 1 is in column E then that formula will sum column E.

Comment: I'm missing something: i recreated your example and im getting a `#REF!` error in `G2`. If i use your formula in `E1` i'm getting 0. But as you explained, this will `sum(B1:E1)` right? This is wrong as it should be `(B1:C1)` in this case...`D` and `E` are not part of the range.

Comment: No, the [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) returns the column number which is 5. If ser_ua is B2:E5 then it only has 4 columns so asking for the 5th column would produce a `#REF!` error. If you need to start ser_ua at B2 then you would need to subtract 1 or ask for the last number from ser_ua, not all of row 1. A wider explanation of what you are trying to do would help me to get you the correct formula.

Comment: sorry Jeeped, i thought i have been clear enough, i try again: `ser_ua` is a named ranged who expands through columns and rows. it is generated by a VBA script so it might have 1 row and 1 column as well as 10000 columns and rows. what i need to obtain is the sum of each row of the named range (only of the named range!) in a cell who actually is 2 columns away from the end of the named range. in fact in my example, column `E` is the sum of `B:C`...and in the explanation i was saing that `B:C` was the named range (but only in that case)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using VBA,:

```
Public Function SumAcross(N As Long) As Variant
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction, RangeToAdd As Range

    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Set RangeToAdd = Intersect(Rows(N), Range("ser_ua"))

    SumAcross = wf.Sum(RangeToAdd)
End Function
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

To improve the volatility of the *UDF*, we can pass it the range being examined:

```
Public Function SumAcross(r As Range, N As Long) As Variant
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction, RangeToAdd As Range

    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Set RangeToAdd = Intersect(Rows(N), Range("ser_ua"))

    SumAcross = wf.Sum(RangeToAdd)
End Function
```

and in a typical worksheet cell:

```
=SumAcross(ser_ua,ROW())
```

Comment: Thanks Gary, nice solution. Unfortunately i'm getting a `#NAME?` error

Comment: Make sure **macros are enabled**  and that the *UDF* code is in a *Standard Module,*

Comment: Ok, solved...it is working. Problem is that if i update one of the cells in the named range, the sum is not being updated unless i refresh it manually (for example cutting and pasting the function in the summing cell)...anyway i can automize it?

Comment: actually, just 1 little question: when adding or removing columns via VBA, the cell will return `####` until i update a cell...i tried with `IF(SumAcross(ser_ua,ROW()) > 0, SumAcross(ser_ua,ROW()), "")` but it is not working...